# SharedElementTransition throughs exception sometimes on minimizing the app

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I've implemented SharedElementTransition in my app. Animation opens from recyclerView item to a ViewPager of next activity. If user changes pages on next screen then based upon final position i change the scrollPosition in recyclerView too using 'reenter' method of activity. It is working fine mostly but sometimes when i start animation and then minimize the app then it through following exception and doesn't even point out the line so i'm unable to handle this exception.

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.transformMatrixToLocal(android.graphics.Matrix)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566385/shared-element-activity-transition-on-android-5

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: yes, it was because when it tries to scroll to a recyclerView to a specific position and view was not created yet and you start transition, then it crashed.